# Is it possible to improve this array intersection code

Tags: c, set-intersection

This is the minimum code to obtain arrays intersection without any repetition in the final array. Can it be improved ?
I think it can't because it uses the minimum number of iteration thanks to the break in the inner loop and also that it can't be parallelized due to a critical section inside the if clause, am I wrong ?
I tried to try this function and the Matlab one (*intersect*) with the same output and the latter is much faster, how is it possible ?

```
int intersection(int* array1, int* array2, int len1, int len2, int size) {
    int j, k, t, intersectC = 0;
    int* tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);


    for (j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < len2; k++) {
            if (array1[j] == array2[k]) {
                    for (t = 0; t < intersectC; t++) {
                        if (tmp[t] == array1[j]) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (t == intersectC) {
                        tmp[intersectC++] = array1[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    free(tmp);
    return intersectC;
}
```

P.S. *size* is the greatest between len1 and len2

Comment: That is O( ( N * M )^2 ), but it's possible to do in O( N+ M ). [Example](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/984b44305021c44ecb86ed155f5c0eed)  (in Perl)

Comment: @ikegami  How can you do it in linear time if the arrays are unsorted?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah By using a dictionary. Adding to a dictionary can be (amortized) O(1). See link I added to earlier comment. (If the range of values is small, an array could be used.)

Comment: @Dresult, What's the range of the inputs (the values in `array1` and `array2`)?

Comment: But yeah, it would be simpler to sort and merge. That would be O( N log N + M log M ), which is still very good. In fact, it should be faster than the first approach I listed for sets of reasonable size.

Comment: If your inputs can be mapped to integers, you can do a radix sort to beat `O(n log n)` sorting.

Comment: @ikegami They are integers in this assignment, but they don't have to be for counting sort to be applicable. They can be somewhat sparse for radix sort, as long as you have a reasonable upper bound on their values (which you do because they're fixed-size machine integer type here).

Comment: @ikegami How does the "grep"-approach functionally differ from your original proposal of using a dictionary?

Comment: @EOF It doesn't. But yeah, radix sort isn't what I thought it was. Comment deleted.

Comment: Try hash table, it's O(N + M) in average, and O(N * M) in the worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, following comments to this question, I used the radix sort to sort the two arrays and a classic intersection algorithm with O(n+m).
Probably, this code is a bit slower than the one posted by @ikegami but much faster than the one in the question.

```
int getMax(int* arr, int n){
    int mx = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > mx)
            mx = arr[i];
    return mx;
}

void countSort(int* arr, int* output, int n, int exp){
    int i, count[10] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int* arr, int n){
    int m = getMax(arr, n);
    int* output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for (int exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10) {
        countSort(arr, output, n, exp);
    }

    free(output);
}

int intersection(int* arr1, int* arr2, int len1, int len2, int size){
    int t, intersectC = 0;
    int* tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    radixsort(arr1, len1);
    radixsort(arr2, len2);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < len1 && j < len2) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            i++;
        else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i])
            j++;
        else /* if arr1[i] == arr2[j] */
        {
            for (t = 0; t < intersectC; t++) {
                if (tmp[t] == arr1[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (t == intersectC) {
                tmp[intersectC++] = arr1[j];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    free(tmp);
    return intersectC;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is O(N<sup>3</sup>), which is insanely bad considering it can be done quickly in O(N).

The following sorts the arrays (using a base2 [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)), and then uses an approach akin to merge sort to find the intersection of the sorted arrays.

(I used `uint32_t`. I leave it to you to adapt to `int`.)

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define ARRAY_LEN(a) ( sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a) )

#define MALLOC(t, n) ( (t*)malloc(sizeof(t) * n) )
#define REALLOC(p, t, n) ( (t*)realloc(p, sizeof(t) * n) )


static void _sort_uint32s(uint32_t *a, size_t n, uint32_t mask) {
   if ( n <= 1 )
      return;

   uint32_t *p = a;
   uint32_t *q = a + n;
   while (1) {
      while (1) {
         if ( ( *p & mask ) != 0 )
            break;
         if ( ++p == q )
            goto DONE_GROUPING;
      }

      while (1) {
         if ( p == --q )
            goto DONE_GROUPING;
         if ( ( *q & mask ) == 0 )
            break;
      }

      uint32_t tmp = *p;
      *p = *q;
      *q = tmp;
   }

DONE_GROUPING:
   mask >>= 1;
   if ( !mask )
      return;

   if ( q > a )
      _sort_uint32s(a, q-a, mask);
   if ( q < a+n )
      _sort_uint32s(q, a+n-q, mask);
}


static void sort_uint32s(uint32_t *a, size_t n) {
   _sort_uint32s(a, n, 0x80000000);
}


static size_t min_size_t(size_t a, size_t b) {
   return a < b ? a : b;
}


// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
// Will modify (sort) a1 and a2.
// Note that *set_p == NULL is possible on success.
static int intersect(uint32_t *a1, size_t n1, uint32_t *a2, size_t n2, uint32_t **set_p, size_t *n_p) {
   size_t n = min_size_t(n1, n2);
   uint32_t *set = MALLOC(uint32_t, n);
   if (!set) {
      *set_p = NULL;
      *n_p   = 0;
      return -1;
   }

   sort_uint32s(a1, n1);
   sort_uint32s(a2, n2);

   n = 0;
   while ( n1 && n2 ) {
      if ( *a1 < *a2 ) {
         while ( --n1 && *(++a1) < *a2 );
      }
      else if ( *a2 < *a1 ) {
         while ( --n2 && *(++a2) < *a1 );
      }
      else {
         uint32_t v = *a1;
         set[n++] = v;
         while ( --n1 && *(++a1) == v );
         while ( --n2 && *(++a2) == v );
      }
   }

   if ( !n ) {
      free(set);
      *set_p = NULL;
      *n_p   = 0;
      return 0;
   }

   uint32_t *tmp = REALLOC(set, uint32_t, n);
   *set_p = tmp ? tmp : set;
   *n_p   = n;
   return 0;
}


int main(void) {
   uint32_t a1[] = { 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15 };
   size_t n1 = ARRAY_LEN(a1);

   uint32_t a2[] = { 12, 1, 5, 2, 2 };
   size_t n2 = ARRAY_LEN(a2);

   uint32_t *set;
   size_t n;
   if ( intersect(a1, n1, a2, n2, &set, &n) < 0 ) {
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Intersection:");
   for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
      printf(" %" PRIu32, set[i]);

   printf("\n");

   free(set);

   return 0;
}
```